# Can't use cut/copy/move/ on desktop

Tags: unity, 12.04, nautilus

I'm using 12.04. I recently noticed that I can't copy/cut/move files on the desktop, Unless I open Nautilus and go to the Desktop folder to complete the actions.

[image]

Comment: Am I correct in guessing I am the only one having this intermittent problem? I'd really like to quash this little bug.

Comment: Just wanted to chime in that I am having the same problem with a 12.04 64 bit fresh install. Changing permissions as described above fixed the problem....but the problem came back. I am exploring Gnome 3 at this point, for this reason as well as the restrictive nature of customizing Unity. Also, the spinning cube has a known bug. The bug has been posted on Launchpad since 11.10. It was the easiest way to change virtual desktops...but I can't use it in Unity with the bug.

Comment: This is a reported bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/988251 . So, sorry for the bounty offered, but the question became off-topic.

Comment: @searchfgold6789 - I have refunded your bounty since this is a confirmed bug report and as such this Q is off-topic as per the FAQ.

Comment: @fossfreedom Thank you, should have smelled this!

Comment: Please tell me how this question was off topic. I guess it is the norm for you guys to pick on the UF staff around here.

Answer (score 0):

check the permissions of your Desktop directory

```
ls -l ~ | grep "Desktop"
```

it looks like a permission problem, try changing permssions with this

```
sudo chmod 755 ~/Desktop -R
```

Comment: Permissions are correct. 8)

Comment: i guess you could try reinstalling nautilus

Comment: I can use right-click within the desktop folder in Nautilus. I only have problems when right-clicking files on the desktop itself.

Answer (score -1):

**Some Background:**

With the changes to **Ubuntu** (starting in **11.04**) the Unity menu-bar (icons, folders, at left-side of screen) replaced the desktop as the place for icons, launchers, etc.

It is possible to get limited use of the desktop by changing certain settings, but the intent is to ***no longer use the desktop*** for this purpose.

The other alternative is to revert/change to using Gnome desktop.

Comment: With 11.04 and 11.10 I was able to alt-click and complete these actions. My other machines running 12.04 are able to do these actions as well. This has only recently become a problem with this machine.

Comment: Which of these are a clean/new install of **12.04**, vs. an upgrade?

Comment: I have three ubuntu 12.04 installs.

One upgrade and one clean install work fine. My production machine is an upgrade. Right-click was working fine in the beginning and just recently started graying out those selections.

Comment: SORRY.  My main machines are an **11.10 (32-bit)** and a new install of **12.04 (64-bit)**.  Neither have any visible desktop icons, so unable to assist further.

Comment: I find this to be very unhelpful. I have been a member of the ubuntu community since 2009 and have not seen any documentation stating that ubuntu/Canonical plans to do away with icons on the desktop. I was under the impression that askubuntu was for questions and answers. Not the implication of opinions.